# Automated deployment using MSBuild to remote Windows Server

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy, teamcity-9.0

I am using **Teamcity** as my **continuous integration server**.

I have a **Visual Studio project** which needs to be **deployed to IIS** as a new application in default website in a **remote Windows server**.

How can I achieve this , either from **command line** or from any one of the **Teamcity build runners**.

I am new to this and have no idea of what to do. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains provides [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Continuous+Delivery+to+Windows+Azure+Web+Sites+%28or+IIS%29) for this scenario.

In a nutshell:

1. Configure web.config transforms to modify application settings based on your target environment (i.e. your test/prod DB connection strings)
2. Enable WebDeploy on the IIS server (for automated delivery of the site package to IIS)
3. Set up TeamCity build step to WebDeploy your project to IIS.